# add static string to grunt usemin result src reference

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

Is there any way to add static string to result of grunt usemin reference?

In my case, grunt usermin replace these line

```
    <script src="bower_components/foo/bar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/example/example.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bar/foo.js"></script>
```

To

```
    <script src="app/d66e52bb.app.js"></script>
```

But I want to add "http://cdn.foo.com/" string to src, so this is what I want.

```
    <script src="http://cdn.foo.com/app/d66e52bb.app.js"></script>
```

Should I change manually every time, or is there clever way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grunt-cdnify: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cdnify

```
cdnify: {
  someTarget: {
    options: {
      base: '//cdn.foo.com/'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'app',
      src: '**/*.{css,html}',
      dest: 'dist'
    }]
  }
}
```